# How to get x,y,z coordinates of each node in a mesh

Tags: ansys

I created a block in ansys and generated a mesh automatically using the meshing tool.  I would now like to get the x,y,z coordinates of each node in the mesh.  How can this be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

x,y,z coordinate values are found under List -> Nodes...

Answer (score 0):

issue `nlist`, to get all nodal information, or if you want only xyz coordinates then issue `nlist,,,,coord`